# TpLink Vlan not working with dd-wrt

Tags: lan, dd-wrt, vlan, wired

swconfig list
swconfig dev  [port |vlan ] (help|set  |get |load |show)

after running command swconfig list i am getting the above reply.
if you could please help.

Router name & Firmware :

[ tplink wr841nd v11   {   DD-WRT v3.0-r41586 std (11/21/19)  ]

Comment: Add more info to the question. as it is this question is missing important info. The command you are typing means nothing, you have combined two separate commands. What exactly are you trying to do? What's your setup look like? Vlan setup for ddwrt/openwrt is very different from vlan setup with normal gear. for instance, the CPU is a port and needs tagging from each vlan. Read the man page for swconfig, it will help you understand the mess that's known as dd-wrt vlaning. If you have the option, use the GUI for setting up vlans. You will still need this https://openwrt.org/docs/techref/swconfig

Comment: Thank You Sir .

Comment: Its running again .

Answer (score -1):

After looking through various articles over some time. I finally got a good understanding of why this happens. What i get is its a bug of openwrt.
Resetting the switch works.
Run `swconfig list`  to see the switch. sometimes its eth1.If so replace eth0 with eth1

```
swconfig dev eth0 set reset
```

Save this as startup

The Script with the VLANS work but on older versions.
Reference:
https://svn.dd-wrt.com/ticket/3736
( Comment 43 )